# how can extract special data from html using jsoup in android

Tags: android, html, css, jsoup

i want to extract special data from this html of [thisWebSite](http://self.shahroodut.ac.ir/Ghaza.aspx?date=970305)

how to extract the words that in this picture by in android studio and store that in a string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Vnj.png)

my java code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text);




    Document document  = Jsoup.parse("http://self.shahroodut.ac.ir/Ghaza.aspx?date=970305");
    Element f1 = document.select("#BulletedListC2").first();
    String food =f1.text();

    textView.setText(food);


}
```

actualy i want to get چلو کباب words and show in a text view pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://self.shahroodut.ac.ir/Ghaza.aspx?date=970305").get();
Element f1 = document.select("#BulletedListC2").first();
```

Comment: hi...at first it say need try catch ...than i have this error ( android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException) and how to save in string?

Comment: To save as string you need to use text() method on f1 object like the following: String result = f1.text(); To avoid the network exception you should move the fetch operation out of the main thread, see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: aha...so when u know that i must use asyntask...say it at first ...not when i faced ui tread problam and asking you ...i solved this problem  thanks